# Why does my getLine in this c function go one line too far?

Tags: c

```
void initializeCar(Car* v,char* mainFileIn)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(mainFileIn, "r"); 
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char* pch;

    while((read = getline(&line, &len,fp)) != -1)
    {
        if(i == 50)
        {
            printf("Cannot hold more than 50 Cars.");
            exit(1);
        }

        pch = strtok(line,",");
        v[i].pid = ++counter;
        v[i].xLocation = (float)strtod(pch,NULL);

        printf("pch: %s\n",pch);

        pch=strtok(NULL,",");
        printf("pch: %s\n",pch);

        v[i].yLocation = (float)strtod(pch,NULL);

        pch = strtok(NULL,",");

        printf("pch: %s\n",pch);

        v[i].velocity = (float)strtod(pch,NULL);

        pch = strtok(NULL,",");

        printf("pch: %s\n",pch);

        v[i].angle = (int)strtol(pch,NULL, 10);
        v[i].start = NULL;
        i++;

    }
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

For some reason everything in my code works except that it reads one extra line after my last line, and gives me a segmentation fault. I cannot figure out why because I modeled my `while` loop according to one of the `getLine` tutorials: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: Have you tried printing the line after you read, to make sure you are getting the data you think you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that you have a blank line at the end of your file, resulting in `pch` being NULL. Your program should deal with lines that don't contain commas.

Comment: @Aaron You can accept my answer ... that's how it works here. And I don't think you need rep to upvote.

Comment: @JimBalter takes 15 rep to upvote. If you upvote the question, he can upvote the answer :) It's true that he should accept the answer in any case.

Comment: @user3386109 Ok, he's got the rep now!

Answer (score -1):

You are capturing the \n character at the end of the line.

Comment: getline does indeed read the \n and include it in line, but this doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Can you explain how I captured the \n character as well in my line? I don't quite understand how to not capture it.

Comment: @Aaron The data that getline returns includes the newline if there is one ... see the documentation. That's what you want; it isn't a problem. This answer is simply off base.